# How to dynamically get IP address from already executed recipe in Chef

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

I am a new to Chef and I am trying to test AWS cluster configuration for 2 db serves + 2 application servers using kitchen-ec2 and facing the following problem:

I cannot dynamically pass **ip_address_1 from recipe#1** (recipe#1 for server1 is completed) **to recipe#2** (which is config recipe for server2 and is being executed). It would be helpful to hear your advice.

One of the things I can do is to explicitly set IP address in .kitchen.yml for each box I am trying to configure , but I am curious if there is any way I can do it on the fly, smth like **Ohai node['ipaddress']** attribute  but more generic, maybe a list of all server IP addresses configured in my cluster.

**recipe#1** - **done** - *server1* is configured, AWS assigned private *ipaddress1*
**recipe#2** - **in progress** - *server2* configuration is being applied but it **requires** *ipaddress1*

Thank you in advance,
Dmitry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but you can access all servers configuration in your recipe via `search`, e.g.:

```
search(:node, 'recipes:"recipe#2"')
```

And then iterate over results to access nodes configuration.

An [example](https://github.com/krukgit/rails_chef_template/blob/master/cookbooks/base/recipes/default.rb#L32), used for populating `/etc/hosts`. I'm using knife-ec2, I'm not sure if kitchen-ec2 provides all these attributes.

[recipes/default.rb](https://github.com/krukgit/rails_chef_template/blob/master/cookbooks/base/recipes/default.rb#L27)

```
template "/etc/hosts" do
  source "etc/hosts.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
  variables(:servers => search(:node, "chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment}"),
            :region => node['ec2']['placement_availability_zone'].match(/(\w*\-\w*\-\d*).*/)[1])
end
```

[templates/default/etc/hosts.erb](https://github.com/krukgit/rails_chef_template/blob/master/cookbooks/base/templates/default/etc/hosts.erb#L11)

```
<% @servers.each do |n| %>
   <% if n["ec2"] %>
      <% region = n["ec2"]["placement_availability_zone"].match(/(\w*\-\w*\-\d*).*/)[1] %>
      <% if region == @region && n["ec2"]["local_ipv4"] %>
<%= n["ec2"]["local_ipv4"] -%> <%= n.name -%> <%= n["ec2"]["hostname"] -%>

      <% elsif n["ec2"]["public_ipv4"] %>
<%= n["ec2"]["public_ipv4"] -%> <%= n.name -%> <%= n["ec2"]["public_hostname"] -%>

      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```